# Series from an integral and output as a function

Tags: functions, series-expansion, output

I have a simple question, I am just stuck on syntax.
I want to have a series of function
$Z(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 !}-\frac{\lambda}{4!} x^4}$ like $Z_N(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n \lambda^n$.

And when I type

```
f[l_] := Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2 - l x^4/24], {x, -Infinity , Infinity}];
g[l, numb_] := Series[f[l], {l, 0, numb}, Assumptions -> {l \[Element] Reals, l > 0}]
g[1,3]
```

it does nothing.

If I do

```
f[l_] := Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2 - l x^4/24], {x, -Infinity , Infinity}];
g[numb_] :=  Series[f[l], {l, 0, numb},  Assumptions -> {l \[Element] Reals, l > 0}]
```

and then try to use the output

```
% /. l -> 3
```

It says *SeriesData::ssdn: Attempt to evaluate a series at the number 3. Returning Indeterminate.*
And I can't copy parts of the output and use it as a function.

Can you tell me, how to do it properly?
And how I was supposed to take output as a function of `l`?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code evaluates without problems on Mathematica v12.2/Windows11. Retry with a fresh kernel!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tryed at Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 11, it is not working...

Comment: Does v11 evaluate `f[l]  (*(Sqrt[3] E^((3/4)/l) BesselK[1/4, 3/(4 l)])/Sqrt[l]*)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The integral can be done once

```
f[l_] = Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2 - l x^4/24], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[3] E^((3/4)/l) BesselK[1/4, 3/(4 l)])/Sqrt[l], 
 Re[l] > 0] *)

g[l_?Positive, numb_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 (Series[f[x] // Normal, {x, 0, numb}] // Normal) /. x -> l

g[1, 3] // Simplify

(* (861 Sqrt[π/2])/512 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood that `Normal` was the main function, that I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
f[l_   ] :=Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2 - l x^4/24], {x, -Infinity, Infinity} ,Assumptions->l>0]
```

**modified:**

```
g[l_, numb_ /; Element[numb, PositiveIntegers]] :=Normal[Series[f[u], {u, 0, numb}]] /. u -> l


g[l,3]
```

$\left(\sqrt{2 \pi }-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}l+\frac{35}{192}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} l^2-\frac{385 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}l^3}{1536}+O\left(l^4\right)\right) (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{\arg(l)+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor }$

```
g[1,3] (*-((163 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2])/512) + Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]*)
```

Comment: when I type `g[1, 3]` it gives the same output `g[1, 3]`. I definitely don't understand something...

Comment: See my modified answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Dear Ulrich, I appreciate your answer, but I need to evaluate it for specific `l`, for example, `l=0.2`. and this is where problems appear.

Comment: why if I write `N[g[l, 1]] /. l -> 1` it says that there is an error?

Comment: It fails if you try % /. l -> 3 after that.

Comment: I confirm that as soon as I try `f[z_, numb_] :=Integrate[Exp[-x^2/2]*(Series[Exp[-z x^4/24], {z, 0, numb}] //Normal), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]; f[0.1, 3]` there is a weird error message "General::ivar: 0.1` is not a valid variable."

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch `f[l]`only has one argument!

Comment: @ХранительРощи Have a look at my modified answer!

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Have a look at my modified answer!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann In the definition given in my comment, `f` has two arguments. I do not see the reason for such an error message of Mma.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Thank you, you have provided also a great answer!